# Working multiple dropper crafting

Tags: minecraft-commands

I have seen a lots of people make global dropper/dispenser crafting that work everywhere .But is that possible to make it multiplayer friendly?

Comment: Flagging question as unclear because it does not specify which edition is being played.

Answer (score 2):

It is, but it takes a lot of command blocks. Every custom crafting table needs an entity marking it, for example an armor stand. This armor stand can be configured by having a command block chain in the following order (note that you should make a dummy objective first, in the examples it's called "success"):

1. `stats entity @e[tag=CustomCraft] set AffectedBlocks @e[type=ArmorStand,c=1] success` This will be used in command block #3
2. `scoreboard players add @e[tag=CustomCraft] success 0` This makes sure the armor stand has a score, otherwise the stats command doesn't work
3. `execute @e[tag=CustomCraft] ~ ~ ~ testforblock ~ ~ ~ dropper -1 <blockdata>` This will test whether the block it's on is a dropper (facing in any direction) has the given
4. `execute @e[tag=CustomCraft] ~ ~ ~ blockdata ~ ~ ~ <new blockdata>` This is used to change the items

Now, for every recipe added, you can extend the chain with another #3 and #4